# FlatList renders with improper height, then a second later, adjusts height

Tags: react-native

I have created a `FlatList` like this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={rows}
        renderItem={renderRow}
      />
</View>
```

It is extremely simple. However on screen load, the flat list height is not full height. It renders at like 70% the actual height. Then after a second it goes to proper height of filling the remainder of the screen.

I want to avoid this "flash" adjustment, and instead, it should initially render with the height it "flash" updates to.

I uploaded a screencast here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO_cF6dCrEU

Comment: I've seen this too - my guess is that it's an issue with the component that needs to be fixed. What solved the issue (somewhat) for me was to dynamically estimate the number of visible cells on the screen and set this in `initialNumToRender`.

Comment: Thanks @sooper that's interesting I'll explore that direction.

Comment: np, let me know how it goes